# How to align graphic and text to opposite sides on a RadioButton

Tags: java, javafx

How do I left align the icon graphic and right align the text of these buttons (Java8)?

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.jensd</groupId>
            <artifactId>fontawesomefx-materialdesignfont</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.22-4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.jensd</groupId>
            <artifactId>fontawesomefx-commons</artifactId>
            <version>8.15</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

[image]

Should be more like this:

[image]

```
import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.materialdesignicons.MaterialDesignIcon;
import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.materialdesignicons.MaterialDesignIconView;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        RadioButton memberButton = new RadioButton("Members");
        memberButton.setGraphic(new MaterialDesignIconView(MaterialDesignIcon.WORKER));
        RadioButton companyButton = new RadioButton("Companies");
        companyButton.setGraphic(new MaterialDesignIconView(MaterialDesignIcon.CITY));
        RadioButton settingsButton = new RadioButton("Settings");
        settingsButton.setGraphic(new MaterialDesignIconView(MaterialDesignIcon.WRENCH));

        stylizeAndSetButtons(memberButton, companyButton, settingsButton);

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(memberButton, companyButton, settingsButton);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static void stylizeAndSetButtons(RadioButton... buttons)
    {
        ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();

        for (RadioButton button : buttons)
        {
            button.setPrefWidth(150);
            button.setMinHeight(50);
            button.getStyleClass().remove("radio-button");
            button.getStyleClass().add("toggle-button");
            button.getStyleClass().add("default");
            

            button.setToggleGroup(group);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I would suggest moving away from `Fontawesomefx` and moving to [`Ikonli`](https://kordamp.org/ikonli/)

Comment: @SedJ601 Is there a reason why?

Comment: 1. More icons. 2. Ease of use. 3. Better Documentation. 4. More recently maintained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do what you want.

Don't use the default `Label`. Use an `HBox` with your icon, a spaceholder pane, and a new `Label`.

---

### Main

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx.FontIcon;


public class App extends Application
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        
        RadioButton companyButton = new RadioButton();        
        FontIcon icon = new FontIcon("bi-alarm");
        Pane placeHolder = new Pane();
        Label label = new Label("Company");
        placeHolder.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        HBox.setHgrow(placeHolder, Priority.ALWAYS);
        HBox hbox = new HBox(icon, placeHolder, label);
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        companyButton.setGraphic(hbox);
        
        stylizeAndSetButtons( companyButton);

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll( companyButton);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static void stylizeAndSetButtons(RadioButton... buttons)
    {
        ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();

        for (RadioButton button : buttons)
        {
            button.setPrefWidth(150);
            button.setMinHeight(50);
            button.getStyleClass().remove("radio-button");
            button.getStyleClass().add("toggle-button");
            button.getStyleClass().add("default");
            

            button.setToggleGroup(group);

        }
    }

}
```

---

### Module-Info

```
module sed.home.testonesimplefx {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires org.kordamp.ikonli.core;
    requires org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx;
    requires org.kordamp.ikonli.bootstrapicons;    
    exports sed.home.testonesimplefx;
}
```

---

### Dependencies

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikonli-javafx</artifactId>
            <version>12.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikonli-bootstrapicons-pack</artifactId>
            <version>12.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

---

### Output

[image]

Note: This uses `Ikonli` but the ideas should be the same.